# Expand a datenum vector

Tags: datetime, octave

I am trying to create a datevec series of dates and times, spaced by 20 minutes, with the minutes column being exactly 0, 20 and 40 with a given starting and ending time. First I create a 20 minute difference value

```
datenum_20_min_diff = datenum( [ 2021 , 1 , 27 , 17 , 0 ] ) - datenum( [ 2021 , 1 , 27 , 16 , 40 ] ) ;
```

and then try to create the required datevec series

```
s = datevec( ( datenum([2021,1,27,22,0]) : datenum_20_min_diff : datenum([2021,1,28,11,0]) )' ) ;
```

which works for the first few entries but then drifts from what I expect. What I get is (with the minutes column slightly tidied up for ease of viewing)

```
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.2000e+01    0            0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.2000e+01   20            0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.2000e+01   40            0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01    0            0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01   19   6.0000e+01
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01   39   6.0000e+01
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01   59   6.0000e+01
```

and what I want/expected is

```
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.2000e+01    0   0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.2000e+01   20   0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.2000e+01   40   0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01    0   0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01   20   0
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01   40   0       
2.0210e+03   1.0000e+00   2.7000e+01   2.3000e+01    0   0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by "cleaning up" the output. The "cleaning" code is shown below,

```
## create a new_date_vec
new_date_vec = datevec( ( datenum(data_ordbk_last) : datenum_20_min_diff : datenum(recent_update_time) )' ) ;

## and clean it up
seconds_60 = find( new_date_vec( : , 6 ) != 0 ) ; new_date_vec( seconds_60 , 6 ) = 0 ; 
minutes_19 = find( new_date_vec( : , 5 ) == 19 ) ; new_date_vec( minutes_19 , 5 ) = 20 ;
minutes_39 = find( new_date_vec( : , 5 ) == 39 ) ; new_date_vec( minutes_39 , 5 ) = 40 ;
minutes_59 = find( new_date_vec( : , 5 ) == 59 ) ; new_date_vec( minutes_59 , 5 ) = 0 ;
new_date_vec( minutes_59 , 4 ) = new_date_vec( minutes_59 , 4 ) .+ 1 ;
hours_24 = find( new_date_vec( : , 4 ) == 24 ) ; new_date_vec( hours_24 , 4 ) = 0 ;
new_date_vec( hours_24 , 3 ) = new_date_vec( hours_24 .+ 1 , 3 ) ;
```

which gives output in the format I want.

Re: Tasos Papastylianou's answer - It was important to get the format just right as later on in my code I am using the ismember function with the optional "rows" argument, so the format of the different rows must match.

Re: Tasos Papastylianou's comment - this is part of a larger project where I read the last line of a file, in which the dates and times are expressed in datevec form and to which new, processed data will eventually be appended. It just seems easier to work with the datvec format, particularly as it's easier to do said processing by looking up specific values in the datevec columns. It's also easier to view the datevec data and check that code is working as expected and not potentially causing problems further down the processing pipeline, just as I did with the original problem.

Comment: Why not just use the original datenums for the ismember operation? Incidentally, I think I would report this behaviour you stumbled upon on the octave bug tracker. Would you like to file a bug (and get more info from the developers?) or would you like me to do it? https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs.html

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thanks for the offer to report the bug on my behalf, but I'll try doing it myself. My first official bug report!

Comment: Rather than a bug, this seems to me a floating-point rounding issue. Your 20 minutes are not exactly 20 minutes, they are a tiny fraction of a second shorter. Datenum are stored as floating-point values after all. Repeatedly adding a floating point value causes accumulation of the rounding error. You should never do this. Instead use `linspace`. If it doesn’t work with datenum, create a float array that you can convert to datenum.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's what I was thinking too, but the more I think about it, the more I think the behaviour of reporting "19min and 60s" does not make sense and should be treated as a bug, regardless of underlying floating-point mechanics. I don't have access to matlab, I was wondering if matlab behaves the same?

Comment: @babelproofreader glad to hear you are eager to report! If you don't mind, leave a comment here with a link to the bug report once you submit it, so we / future users can follow up! :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Done, as requested. https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?59979

Comment: @Tasos: But it probably is computed as 19 min 59.999999 s, which is then displayed as 60 s. But the display and computation are separate elements. I think the general concept is wrong, using fractions of a day to do computation in minutes. 1/1440 can probably not be expressed exactly as a binary fraction. The solution would be to generate the datevec directly, not use datenum.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think generating the datevec directly would probably entail all sorts of other problems, since it is not a 'smart' format in the datetime sense. Alas, this is a weakness of the datenum construct. Octave provides parallel TM_struct / unix timestamp based functions too, which would probably work better here, but those functions do not have interoperability with datenum/datevec. The way I would have approached this problem would be to rely on datestr and compare strings of the desired components, OR rely exclusively on datenum and perform floating-point comparisons (not equality).

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'drift'. It's just that at some point your 20 minute interval starts getting expressed as 19 minutes and 60 seconds (=20 minutes).

I don't know why, but in theory the two are equivalent and you should not care about it. If you are worried about 'formatting' the date to obtain an output that is more visually meaningful, use a formatting function. E.g. `datestr(s)` will give you what you expect.

<sub>PS: "20 minutes expressed as fraction of a 24h-day" is as simple `20 / 24 / 60`. No real need for the first line.</sub>